# Reactjs: How to use drawImage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-image-crop

In my project, using react-image-crop package to crop images. But which provides some errors

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactCrop  from 'react-image-crop'
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css'



export const Imagecrop = () => {
    
    const [src, setSrc] = useState(null)
    const handleFileChange = e =>{
        console.log(e.target.files[0])
        setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
        console.log("src", src)
    }
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [crop, setCrop] = useState()
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);    

    const cropImageNow = () => {
        console.log("image", image)
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const scaleX = image?.naturalWidth / image?.width;
        const scaleY = image?.naturalHeight / image?.height;
        canvas.width = crop.width;
        canvas.height = crop.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      
        const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
        canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio;
        canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio;
        ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';

        // ctx.drawImage(
        //   image,
        //   crop.x * scaleX,
        //   crop.y * scaleY,
        //   crop.width * scaleX,
        //   crop.height * scaleY,
        //   0,
        //   0,
        //   crop.width,
        //   crop.height,
        // );
          
        // Converting to base64
        const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        setResult(base64Image);
      };

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <input type='file' accept='image/*' onChange={handleFileChange} />
                </div>
                <div className='col-6'>
                {src && (
                    <ReactCrop crop={crop} aspect={800 / 200} onChange={setCrop}>
                        <img src={src} />
                    </ReactCrop>
                    
                    
                )}
                {src && <button onClick={cropImageNow}>crop</button>}
                
                </div>
                {result && <div>
                    <img src={result} alt="croped image" className='img-fluid'/>
                    </div>}

            
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The result is
[image]

when uncommenting these lines

```
ctx.drawImage(
          image,
          crop.x * scaleX,
          crop.y * scaleY,
          crop.width * scaleX,
          crop.height * scaleY,
          0,
          0,
          crop.width,
          crop.height,
        );
```

which produces an error

[image]

How to get the cropped image in the last column? Is there any possible way to use react-image-crop to show cropped images without using drawImage? Please give me a solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a solution using react-image-crop to crop image you can see in sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1dtqe?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: When I tried that in local the selected image and cropped image are not visible.